# Neat way to define arbitraly order Tensor in Julia

Tags: julia, metaprogramming

I want to define an arbitrary order Tensor-like type in Julia. Here, Tensor-like means something like `Vector{Vector{Vector{T}}`. My trial was the code below:

```
function Tensor(N::Int, T::DataType)
    N==0 && return eval(T)
    return Tensor(N-1, eval(Expr(:curly, :Vector, T)))
end
```

And declaration would be `data = Tensor(3, Float64)[]`. Regarding this, I have two questions. 1) Is there a neater way to do this? 2) I prefer declaration using braces like `data = Tensor{3, Float64}[]` rather than using parentheses. How can I do this maybe by means of metaprogramming?

Comment: How in your use case do you not want to just say data = Array{Float64, 3} ?

Comment: Oh, That's exactly what I want... (I'm a newbie)

Comment: You should never use `eval` and especially not for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know the size of tensor.
Let

```
d = (4,3,2)
```

be the size of your tensor. You can create it in two ways:

1. Arrays of zeros

Use `zeros()` - see the example below:

```
julia> zeros(Float64,d)
4×3×2 Array{Float64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0

[:, :, 2] =
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
```

2. Not initialized (faster, note the garbage values)

Use `Array` type constructor:

```
julia> x = Array{Float64,length(d)}(undef,d) 
4×3×2 Array{Float64,3}:                      
[:, :, 1] =                                  
 5.34466e-316  5.34466e-316  5.34467e-316    
 5.34466e-316  5.34467e-316  5.34467e-316    
 5.34466e-316  5.34467e-316  5.34467e-316    
 5.34466e-316  1.51858e-316  5.34468e-316    

[:, :, 2] =                                  
 1.51858e-316  5.34487e-316  0.0             
 1.51858e-316  5.34487e-316  0.0             
 1.51858e-316  5.34429e-316  0.0             
 1.51858e-316  5.16938e-316  0.0
```